# getting error in every line i have used <<

Tags: visual-c++, operators, iostream, fstream, ofstream

> error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : >could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from >'std::string'    c:\documents and settings\rcs\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects...

the Code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Pacient.h"

using namespace std;

void ruajKartele(Pacient patient)
{
    int mosha;
    char gjinia;
    string foo=patient.getEmer();
    string skedar=foo;
    ofstream file;
    file.open(skedar, ios::app);
    skedar<<foo+"\n";
    mosha=patient.getMosha();
    gjinia=patient.getGjinia();
    foo=patient.getDiagnoza();
    skedar<<mosha<<"\n"<<gjinia<<"\n"<<foo<<"\n";
    foo=patient.getPrognoza();
    skedar<<foo+"\n";
    skedar<<"-----\n"; //5
    skedar.close();
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
//Pacient structure:
    #include <string>
class Pacient
{
protected:
    std::string emer;
    int mosha;
    char gjinia;
    std::string diagnoza;
    std::string prognoza;

public:
    Pacient(void);
~Pacient(void);
void setEmer(std::string);
void setMosha (int);
void setGjinia(char);
void setDiagnoza(std::string);
void setPrognoza(std::string);
std::string getEmer(void);
int getMosha(void);
char getGjinia(void);
std::string getDiagnoza(void);
std::string getPrognoza(void);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string skedar=foo;
ofstream file;
file.open(skedar, ios::app);
skedar<<foo+"\n";
```

`skedar` is a `std::string`, that (apparently) represents a path. `file` is an `ofstream`. If you want to write to that stream, you can't `skedar << "whatever";`, you need to output to the `ofstream`:

```
file << foo << "\n";
```

Same for `skedar.close();`: it's the *file* you want to close, not the string that represents its filename.

Comment: I forgot to mention the skedar.close() thing earlier. I'm adding it in now. +1 for you! :)

Comment: thank you so much!, i have been working with some projects for so long my eyes have gone blind apparently! 

I cant tell you how much u just helped!

Answer (score 0):

You've used the << operator on skedar, which is a string. Strings don't have an << operator. You probably meant to use something like this:

```
file<<skedar<<mosha<<"\n"<<gjinia<<"\n"<<foo<<"\n";
```

I also noticed that you had:

```
skedar.close();
```

Instead of this:

```
file.close();
```

I forgot to add that in the first time around.